# Using Publish Subscribe channel in Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

We have the below XML configuration for a rest service and Oracle Stored Proc. The use case is about handling Oracle SP errors.

When the Oracle SP throws error, we need to achieve 2 things:

1. we need to send a json response back to the client in the format 
   {"status": false,"message": "Oracle SP error payload"}
2. Send an email out.

The configuration is working as expected when Oracle SP throws error. But when the email send fails ( gave a wrong host), client is receiving error in the below format.  The Oracle SP error message is not sent back.

```
---- Json message received by client when email send fails:------
{
 "timestamp": 1501639940143,
 "status": 500,
 "error": "Internal Server Error",
 "exception": "org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException",
 "message": "failure occurred in error-handling flow; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#0$child#2.handler]; nested exception is org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: xxx.com;..",
 "path": "/init/5c82d1f4-e550-4bb1-be9c-8d0ddbc7f4401/NEW"
}
```

How do I send response in the expected json format - {"status": false,"message": Oracle SP error payload}?

Also how to handle the email send error.i.e may be how to store the email error in a DB table?

### XML Configuration:

```
<int:channel id="spOutClobChannel"/>
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="gatewayErrorChannel"/>


<int-http:inbound-gateway
    request-channel="gatewayInitChannel"
    error-channel="gatewayErrorChannel"
    supported-methods="GET"
    path="/init/{refId}/{refStatus}"        
    payload-expression="#pathVariables.refStatus">

  <int-http:header name="UNIQUE_PROCESS_ID" expression="#pathVariables.refId"/>

</int-http:inbound-gateway>

<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway
            id="sp-get-data"
            data-source="dataSource"
            request-channel="gatewayInitChannel"
            reply-channel="spOutClobChannel".... >
    ...
    ...             
</int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>


<int:transformer input-channel="spOutClobChannel"    expression='{"status": true, "message": "RECEIVED"}'/>
<int:transformer input-channel="gatewayErrorChannel" expression='{"status": false,"message": payload.message}'/>

<int:transformer expression="payload.failedMessage.headers['UNIQUE_PROCESS_ID']"   
               input-channel="gatewayErrorChannel" output-channel="appEmailChannel"/>

<int:chain input-channel="appEmailChannel" >
    <int-mail:header-enricher>
        <int-mail:from     value="${email.from}"/>
        <int-mail:to       value="${email.to}"/>
        <int-mail:subject  value="${email.subject}"/>
        <int-mail:content-type value="text/html"/>
   </int-mail:header-enricher> 
   <int-mail:outbound-channel-adapter   host="${email.host}" />
</int:chain>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid errors thrown from the `appEmailChannel` flow, plus get a gain do not wait for the successful email shipment, it would be better to add  to your `gatewayErrorChannel` an `executor` configuration. This way all the subscribers to this publish-subscriber channel will be performed in parallel and in their own threads. Therefore any exception in those threads won't impact the reply to the `<int-http:inbound-gateway>` which you've done with the

```
<int:transformer input-channel="gatewayErrorChannel" expression='{"status": false,"message": payload.message}'/>
```

> Also how to handle the email send error.i.e may be how to store the email error in a DB table?

With this goal you can use `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` with its `trapException = true` and `failureChannel` properties.

This advice can be configured with the `request-handler-advice-chain` sub-element.

See [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain) and [Sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/retry-and-more) on the matter.

Comment: As you mentioned, if we add an executor configuration to gatewayErrorChannel;  the <transformer> and email component will be executed in their own threads.  At what point the Caller thread(original caller) returns and how will the caller thread  get the transformed Json response(status = false) ?

Comment: The request-reply algorithm is based on the `TemporaryReplyChannel ` header which uses blocking wait with the `CountDownLatch`. Therefore it doesn't matter from which thread the `countDown()` is called.